# Antiderivative of $(1+x^3)^{-1/3}$.

Tags: integration, substitution

I tried multiple substitutions while trying to solve for:
$$
\int\frac{{\rm d}x}{(1+x^3)^{\frac{1}{3}}}
$$
 According to some online sources it is non-elementary, although the question was taken from a book that says otherwise.

Any ideas?

Closest I got was using
$$u=\frac{1}{x(1+x^3)^{1/3}}$$
but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you tried Wolfarmalpha?

Comment: Yes, it says it is non elementary, I'm asking because it had bugs before so I just want to be sure I'm not missing anything.

Comment: What is the book that you got this problem from? It's possible that there is a typo (knowing which book it is would allow use to look for an errata, for example, or perhaps the book is widely known to contain some mistakes or unproven statements)

Comment: I will ask my teacher for the name of the book.

Comment: Maybe you can work backwards from a closed form: $$-\frac{1}{3} \ln \left(1-\frac{x}{\sqrt[3]{x^3+1}}\right)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\operatorname{arctan}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left(\frac{2 x}{\sqrt[3]{x^3+1}}+1\right)\right)+\frac{1}{6} \ln \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt[3]{x^3+1}}+\frac{x^2}{\left(x^3+1\right)^{2/3}}+1\right)$$

Answer (score 6):

$$I = \int\frac{{\rm d}x}{(1+x^3)^{\frac{1}{3}}}$$
Let $$u = \frac{x}{\sqrt[3]{1+x^3}} \implies u^3 = \frac{x^3}{1+x^3} = 1-\frac{1}{1+x^3}$$

(**Note:** How did I get this strange substitution? See the note at the end)

$$\implies 1 + x^3 = \frac{1}{1-u^3}$$

Also,
$$du = \frac{1}{(1+x^3)^{4/3}}dx = \frac{1}{1+x^3}\frac{1}{(1+x^3)^{1/3}}dx$$
$$\implies (1+x^3)du = \frac{dx}{(1+x^3)^{1/3}} $$
$$\implies \frac{du}{1-u^3} = \frac{dx}{(1+x^3)^{1/3}}$$

Hence
$$I = \int\frac{du}{1-u^3}$$

This is quite a standard integral leading to:

$$ I = \frac{1}{6}\ln(u^2+u+1) -\frac{1}{3}\ln(1-u) +\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\arctan\left(\frac{2u+1}{\sqrt3}\right) + C$$

Using $u = \frac{x}{\sqrt[3]{1+x^3}}$, we get

$$I = \boxed{\frac{1}{6}\ln\left(\frac{x^2}{(1+x^3)^{2/3}}+\frac{x}{\sqrt[3]{1+x^3}}+1\right) -\frac{1}{3}\ln(1-\frac{x}{\sqrt[3]{1+x^3}}) +\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\arctan\left(\frac{\frac{2x}{\sqrt[3]{1+x^3}}+1}{\sqrt3}\right) + C}$$

---

**Solving the 'standard integral':**

$$I = \int\frac{du}{1-u^3}$$

Using Partial Fractions, we get

$$ I = \frac{1}{3}\int\frac{u+2}{u^2+u+1}du - \frac{1}{3}\int\frac{du}{u-1}$$

$$ = \frac{1}{6}\int\frac{2u+1}{u^2+u+1}du + \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{du}{u^2+u+1} - \frac{1}{3}\ln(|u-1|)$$

$$ = \frac{1}{6}ln|u^2+u+1| -\frac{1}{3}ln|1-u| + \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{du}{(u+\frac{1}{2})^2 + (\frac{\sqrt3}{4})^2}$$

$$ = \frac{1}{6}ln|u^2+u+1| -\frac{1}{3}ln|1-u| + \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{\sqrt3}\arctan((u+\frac{1}{2})/\frac{\sqrt3}{2}) + C$$

$$ I = \frac{1}{6}ln|u^2+u+1| -\frac{1}{3}ln|1-u| + \frac{1}{\sqrt3}\arctan\left(\frac{2u+1}{\sqrt3}\right) + C$$

---

**Substitution:** It's tedious but here it is:

Let $x^3 = \tan^2\theta \implies 3x^2dx = 2\tan\theta \sec^2\theta d\theta$
$$\implies \frac{dx}{(1+x^3)^{1/3}} = \frac{2\tan\theta \sec^2\theta}{3\tan^{4/3}\theta \sec^{2/3}\theta} d\theta = \frac{2}{3}\frac{\sec\theta \sec^{1/3}\theta}{\tan^{1/3}\theta}d\theta = \frac{2}{3}\frac{d\theta}{\cos\theta\sin^{1/3}\theta}$$

Using $$\sin^3\phi = \sin\theta \implies 3\sin^2\phi\cos\phi d\phi = \cos\theta d\theta = (1-\sin^6\phi)^{1/2}d\theta$$
$$\implies d\theta = \frac{3\sin^2\phi\cos\phi}{(1-\sin^6\phi)^{1/2}}d\phi$$

$$\implies \frac{2}{3}\frac{d\theta}{\cos\theta\sin^{1/3}\theta} = \frac{2}{3}\frac{3\sin^2\phi \cos\phi}{(1-\sin^6\phi)\sin\phi}d\phi = \frac{2\sin\phi\cos\phi}{1-sin^6\phi}d\phi$$

Using $\sin^2\phi = u \implies du = 2\sin\phi\cos\phi d\phi$
$$\frac{2\sin\phi\cos\phi}{1-sin^6\phi}d\phi = \frac{du}{1-u^3}$$

Working backwards, we have:
$$u = \sin^2\phi = \sin^{2/3}\theta = \left(\frac{\tan\theta}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta}}\right)^{2/3} = \left(\frac{x^{3/2}}{(1+x^3)^{1/2}}\right)^{2/3} = \frac{x}{(1+x^3)^{1/3}}$$

Comment: Nice substitution, but why you choose $\sin \phi =\sin^3 \theta$ ?

Comment: @Ameryr  I think that was what I did. I’ll verify again and update after some time.

Comment: @Ameryr I have added an explanation of the variable substitution to the end.