# Solving $\int \frac{6x^{3}+7x^2-12x+1}{\sqrt{x^2+4x+6}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have previously asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3196491/515527) the following integral:$$\int \frac{6x^{3}+7x^2-12x+1}{\sqrt{x^2+4x+6}}dx.$$

In the meantime I have received an answer from Achille Hui [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3196592/515527), but
there are still some points that I don't understand from his answer.

---

At some point there is:

> 1. Set $B(y)$ to $ay^2 + by + c$, RHS($*1$) becomes $(6-3a)y^3 + \cdots$. We should fix $a$ to $2$.
> 2. Repeat this procedure once more, we find $c$ should be fixed to $24$.

I don't understand how does he fix these numbers? Does he let them equal $0$ to obtain the final result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used a slightly different approach using a substitution. This makes the integral into a routine computational effort.

$$I = \int \frac{6x^{3}+7x^2-12x+1}{\sqrt{x^2+4x+6}}dx$$
$$ = \int \frac{6x^{3}+7x^2-12x+1}{\sqrt{(x+2)^2+2}}dx$$
Let $x + 2 = \sqrt2\tan\theta \implies dx = \sqrt2\sec^2\theta\ d\theta\text{ and } x=\sqrt2\tan\theta-2$

$$\implies I = \int\frac{12\sqrt2\tan^3\theta -58\tan^2\theta+32\sqrt2\tan\theta+5}{\sqrt2\sec\theta}\sqrt2\sec^2\theta\ d\theta$$
$$= \int (12\sqrt2\tan^3\theta\sec\theta -58\tan^2\theta\sec\theta+32\sqrt2\tan\theta\sec\theta+5\sec\theta)\ d\theta$$

---

$$ = \color{red}{12\sqrt2\int (\sec^2\theta-1)\tan\theta\sec\theta\ d\theta} - \color{green}{58\int(\sec^2\theta-1)\sec\theta\ d\theta} + 32\sqrt2\int\tan\theta\sec\theta\ d\theta + 5\int\sec\theta\ d\theta$$

$$ = \color{red}{12\sqrt2\int (\sec^2\theta)\tan\theta\sec\theta\ d\theta -12\sqrt2\int\tan\theta\sec\theta\ d\theta} - \color{green}{58\int(\sec^2\theta)\sec\theta\ d\theta +\underline{58\int\sec\theta\ d\theta}} + 32\sqrt2\int\tan\theta\sec\theta\ d\theta + \underline{5\int\sec\theta\ d\theta}$$

$$ = 12\sqrt2\left(\frac{\sec^3\theta}{3} -\sec\theta\right) - 58\int\sec^3\theta\ d\theta + 32\sqrt2\sec\theta + 63\int\sec\theta\ d\theta$$

$$ = 4\sqrt2\sec^3\theta + 20\sqrt2\sec\theta - 58\int\sec^3\theta\ d\theta+ 63\int\sec\theta\ d\theta$$
$$ = 4\sqrt2\sec^3\theta + 20\sqrt2\sec\theta \color{green}{- 29}\left(\sec\theta\tan\theta + \color{green}{\ln(\sec\theta+\tan\theta)}\right) + \color{green}{63\ln(\sec\theta+\tan\theta)}$$

Using $\ln(z+\sqrt{z^2+1}) = \sinh^{-1}z$, we get

$$I = 4\sqrt2\sec\theta\left(\sec^2\theta + 5 -\frac{29}{4\sqrt2}\tan\theta\right) + \color{green}{34\sinh^{-1}(\tan\theta)}$$

---

Using $\tan\theta = \dfrac{x+2}{\sqrt2}\text{ and } \sec\theta = \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+4x+6}}{\sqrt2}$, we get

$$I = 4\sqrt{x^2+4x+6}\left(\frac{x^2+4x+6}{2} + 5 - \frac{29}{4\sqrt2}\frac{x+2}{\sqrt2}\right) + 34\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{x+2}{\sqrt2}\right)$$
$$ = \sqrt{x^2+4x+6}\left(2x^2+8x+12+20-\frac{29}{2}x-29\right) + 34\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{x+2}{\sqrt2}\right)$$
$$ = \boxed{\sqrt{x^2+4x+6}\left(2x^2-\frac{13}{2}x+3\right) + 34\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{x+2}{\sqrt2}\right)}$$

Comment: I am sorry, but I am getting stuck here: $$= \int (12\sqrt2\tan^3\theta\sec\theta -58\tan^2\theta\sec\theta+32\sqrt2\color{red}\tan\theta\sec\theta+5\sec\theta)\ d\theta$$

$$ = 12\sqrt2\int (\sec^2\theta-1)\tan\theta\sec\theta\ d\theta - 58\int(\sec^2\theta-1)\sec\theta\ d\theta + 32\sqrt2\sec\theta + 5\int\sec\theta\ d\theta$$ Where does the $tanx$ go for this line?

Comment: @JamesWarthington the whole expression is under the integral sign and we have $\int \tan\theta \sec\theta\ d\theta = \sec\theta\ $, so the next line has the $32\sqrt2\sec\theta$

Comment: @JamesWarthington have added the additional step for clarity

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer, I am stuck here, could you explain further? How does the 5 in the above line become 63 down below?$$ = 12\sqrt2\int (\sec^2\theta-1)\tan\theta\sec\theta\ d\theta - 58\int(\sec^2\theta- 1)\sec\theta\ d\theta + 32\sqrt2\int\tan\theta\sec\theta\ d\theta +  \color{red}{5}\int\sec\theta\ d\theta$$
$$ = 12\sqrt2\left(\frac{\sec^3\theta}{3} -\sec\theta\right) - 58\int\sec^3\theta\ d\theta + 32\sqrt2\sec\theta + \color{red}{63}\int\sec\theta\ d\theta$$

Comment: @JamesWarthington look at the underlined terms and colors in the edited answer now. The $58$ and $5$ coefficients get added.

Comment: I have some problems following this line:

$$ = 4\sqrt2\sec^3\theta + 20\sqrt2\sec\theta - \color{red}{29\left(\sec\theta\tan\theta + \ln(\sec\theta+\tan\theta)\right)} + 63\ln(\sec\theta+\tan\theta)$$

Using $\ln(z+\sqrt{z^2+1}) = \sinh^{-1}z$, we get

$$I = 4\sqrt2\sec\theta\left(\sec^2\theta + 5 -\color{red}{\frac{29}{4\sqrt2}}\tan\theta\right) + \color{green}{34\sinh^{-1}(\tan\theta)}$$

How does the red part turn into $\dfrac{29}{4\sqrt{2}}\tan\theta$ and $63\ln(\sec\theta+\tan\theta)$ into ${34\sinh^{-1}(\tan\theta)}$  Thank you so much again!

Comment: I have some problems following this line:

$$ = 4\sqrt2\sec^3\theta + 20\sqrt2\sec\theta - 29\left(\sec\theta\tan\theta + \ln(\sec\theta+\tan\theta)\right) + \color{green}{63\ln(\sec\theta+\tan\theta)}$$

Using $\ln(z+\sqrt{z^2+1}) = \sinh^{-1}z$, we get

$$I = 4\sqrt2\sec\theta\left(\sec^2\theta + 5 -\color{red}{\frac{29}{4\sqrt2}}\tan\theta\right) + \color{green}{34\sinh^{-1}(\tan\theta)}$$

How does $63\ln(\sec\theta+\tan\theta)$ turn into $34\sinh^{-1}(\tan\theta)$

Comment: The previous term beings in a $-29\ln(\sec\theta + \tan\theta)$, so $63-29 = 34$

Comment: Thank you user1952500 for your patience. Now I don't know how do you transform $\color{red}{\ln(\sec\theta+\tan\theta)}$ into $\color{red}{\sinh^{-1}(\tan\theta)}$


$$ = 4\sqrt2\sec^3\theta + 20\sqrt2\sec\theta \color{green}{- 29}\left(\sec\theta\tan\theta + \color{green}{\ln(\sec\theta+\tan\theta)}\right) + \color{green}{63\ln(\sec\theta+\tan\theta)}$$

$$I = 4\sqrt2\sec\theta\left(\sec^2\theta + 5 -\frac{29}{4\sqrt2}\tan\theta\right) + \color{green}{34\sinh^{-1}(\tan\theta)}$$

Comment: I know that $\ln(z+\sqrt{z^2+1}) = \sinh^{-1}x$ is the definition of $\sinh^{-1}x$. But the transformation is not obvious to me.

Comment: @JamesWarthington $\ln(\sec\theta+\tan\theta) = \ln(\sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta} + \tan\theta) = \sinh^{-1}(\tan\theta) \text{ with } z = \tan\theta$

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience. I have one last question:

How do you come up with this substitution in the first place? Do you put this integral into Wolfram to see the end result, then come back and decide what the substitution should be?

$\tan\theta = \dfrac{x+2}{\sqrt2}\text{ and } \sec\theta = \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+4x+6}}{\sqrt2}$

Comment: @JamesWarthington that wasn't inspired by wolfram but rather some intuition after solving many problems. Here we have a square-root and what I want to do is to somehow remove the radical. It is $\sqrt{(x+2)^2 + 2}$, so if I make $(x+2)$ as $\sqrt2\tan\theta$, I can get $\sqrt{2(1+\tan^2\theta} = \sqrt2\sec\theta$. I have added more of my thought process in another answer(https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3203964/antiderivative-of-1x3-1-3/3204021#3204021). Look at the substitution rationale there.